# How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?

Tags: list, dart, equality

I'm comparing two lists in Dart like this:

```dart
main() {
    if ([1,2,3] == [1,2,3]) {
        print("Equal");
    } else {
        print("Not equal");
    }   
}
```

But they are never equal. There doesn't seem to be an `equal()` method in the Dart API to compare Lists or Collections. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

To complete Gunter's answer: the recommended way to compare lists for equality (rather than identity) is by using the Equality classes from the following package

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

**Edit**: prior to 1.13, it was <del>import 'package:collection/equality.dart';</del>

E.g.:

```dart
Function eq = const ListEquality().equals;
print(eq([1,'two',3], [1,'two',3])); // => true
```

The above prints `true` because the corresponding list elements are `identical()`. If you want to (deeply) compare lists that might contain other collections then instead use:

```dart
Function deepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
List list1 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
List list2 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
print(    eq(list1, list2)); // => false
print(deepEq(list1, list2)); // => true
```

There are other Equality classes that can be combined in many ways, including equality for `Map`s. You can even perform an **unordered** (deep) comparison of collections:

```dart
Function unOrdDeepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals;
List list3 = [3, [[],'a'], 1];
print(unOrdDeepEq(list2, list3)); // => true
```

For details see the [package API documentation](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection). As usual, to use such a package you must list it in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  collection: any
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with lists of objects. I have a list of objects and even when they match, I get `false`. Both with `eq` and `deepEq`.

Comment: For complex object comparison, ensure to implement `Equatable` for this to work on `DeepCollectionEquality`

Answer (score 211):

For those using Flutter, it has the native function [`listEquals`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html), which compares for deep equality.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

var list1 = <int>[1, 2, 3];
var list2 = <int>[1, 2, 3];

assert(listEquals(list1, list2) == true);
```

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

var list1 = <int>[1, 2, 3];
var list2 = <int>[3, 2, 1];

assert(listEquals(list1, list2) == false);
```

Note that, [according to the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html):

> The term "deep" above refers to the first level of equality: if the elements are maps, lists, sets, or other collections/composite objects, then the values of those elements are not compared element by element unless their equality operators (`Object.operator==`) do so.

Therefore, if you're looking for limitless-level equality, check out [`DeepCollectionEquality`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/DeepCollectionEquality-class.html), as suggested by [Patrice Chalin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333042/6696558).

Also, there's [`setEquals`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/setEquals.html) and [`mapEquals`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/mapEquals.html) if you need such feature for different collections.

Answer (score 23):

Collections in Dart have no inherent equality. Two sets are not equal, even if they contain exactly the same objects as elements.

The [collection library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection) provides methods to define such an equality. In this case, for 
example

```
IterableEquality().equals([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

is an equality that considers two lists equal exactly if they contain identical elements.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the built-in listEquals, setEquals, and mapEquals function to check for equality now.

Here's the link to the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html

Comment: Those are for Flutter and are not available in pure Dart.

For Dart, you can use the `collection` package.

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution to compare the equality of two list of int in Dart can be to use Sets (without checking the order of the element in the list) :

```
void main() {
  var a = [1,2,3];
  var b = [1,3,2];
  
  var condition1 = a.toSet().difference(b.toSet()).isEmpty;
  var condition2 = a.length == b.length;
  var isEqual = condition1 && condition2;
  print(isEqual); // Will print true
}
```

Comment: this one is more suitable to my case, because I am trying to avoid using an extra package

Comment: nerdy and effective !

Answer (score 9):

I just stumbled upon this

```dart
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  if (const IterableEquality().equals([1,2,3],[1,2,3])) {
  // if (const SetEquality().equals([1,2,3].toSet(),[1,2,3].toSet())) {
      print("Equal");
  } else {
      print("Not equal");
  }
}
```

more info https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/tree/master/dart/pkg/collection

Answer (score 5):

While this question is rather old, the feature still hasn't landed natively in Dart.  I had a need for deep equality comparison (`List<List>`), so I borrowed from above now with recursive call:

```dart
bool _listsAreEqual(list1, list2) {
 var i=-1;
 return list1.every((val) {
   i++;
   if(val is List && list2[i] is List) return _listsAreEqual(val,list2[i]);
   else return list2[i] == val;
 });
}
```

Note: this will still fail when mixing Collection types (ie `List<Map>`) - it just covers `List<List<List>>` and so-on.

Latest dart issue on this seems to be https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2217 (last updated May 2013).

Answer (score 3):

The Built Collections library offers immutable collections for Dart that include equality, hashing, and other goodies.

If you're doing something that requires equality there's a chance you'd be better off with immutability, too.

http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/built_collection/0.3.1/index.html#built_collection/built_collection

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes one want to compare not the lists themselves but some objects (class instances) that contain list(s)

Let you have a class with list field, like

```
class A {
  final String name;
  final List<int> list;

  A(this.name, this.list);
}
```

and want to compare its instances, you can use [equatable package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/equatable)

```
class A extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final List<int> list;
  
  A(this.name, this.list);
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name, list];
}
```

and then simply compare objects using `==`

```
final x = A('foo', [1,2,3]);
final y = A('foo', [1,2,3]);
print(x == y); // true
```

Comment: I don't think Equatable provides a constructor you can use as you do in your example, and regardless you are required to provide an implementation of a `props` getter. I.e. the constructor as just `A(this.name, this.list);` and an `@override` annotated `List<Object> get props => [name, list];`. Maybe the library changed since you wrote your answer.

Comment: I went through the Equatable repository, and versions as of `0.6.x` require the changes I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The most convenient option would be to create an [extension method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) on the `List` class.

```dart
extension on List {
  bool equals(List list) {
    if(this.length!=list.length) return false;
    return this.every((item) => list.contains(item));
  }
}
```

What the above code does is that it checks to see if every single `item` from the first list (`this`) is contained in the second list (`list`). This only works, however, if both lists are of the same length. **You can, of course, substitute in one of the other solutions or modify this solution, I am just showing this for the sake of convenience.** Anyway, to use this extension, do this:

```dart
List list1, list2
list1.equals(list2);
```

Comment: Your extension method is wrong. `[1, 2, 2, 3].equals([1, 3, 3, 2])` returns `true`

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```dart
try {
  Expect.listEquals(list1, list2);
} catch (var e) {
  print("lists aren't equal: $e");
}
```

Example:

```dart
main() {
  List<int> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  List<int> list2 = new List.from(list1);
  try {
    Expect.listEquals(list1, list2);
  } catch (var e) {
    print("lists aren't equal: $e");
  }
  list1.removeLast();
  try {
    Expect.listEquals(list1, list2);
  } catch (var e) {
    print("Lists aren't equal: $e");
  }
}
```

Second try prints:

```dart
Lists aren't equal: Expect.listEquals(list length, expected: <4>, actual: <5>) fails
```

Comment: Is this Equal class defined in the API? I couldn't track it down if it is. It would seem that it would make the most sense for these classes to expose an operator or method for comparing equality with Dart would then use with the == operator.

Comment: Agreed. It's actually the Expect class in dart:core.  Oddly, unless I'm misreading it, the comments under Expect.listEquals states that this is different than the standard check for equality used by the list implementation, which as you and Lars pointed out, doesn't seem to actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

Before things work, you can use this:

```dart
  /**
   * Returns true if the two given lists are equal.
   */
  bool _listsAreEqual(List one, List two) {
    var i = -1;
    return one.every((element) {
      i++;

      return two[i] == element;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It will crash if first list is bigger

Comment: And return true for [3, 5] and [3, 5, 7, 9]

Answer (score 1):

```
bool areListsEqual(var list1, var list2) {
    // check if both are lists
    if(!(list1 is List && list2 is List)
        // check if both have same length
        || list1.length!=list2.length) {
        return false;
    }
     
    // check if elements are equal
    for(int i=0;i<list1.length;i++) {
        if(list1[i]!=list2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
     
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to **compare the equality of two list of int** in Dart can be to compare it as String using join() :

```
var a = [1,2,3,0];
var b = [1,2,3,4];

a.join('') == b.join('') ? return true: return false;
```

Comment: This is not reliable. Consider [12, 3] and [1, 23]

Comment: Thanks for, you are right it does not work in your specific example.

Comment: It could work with a sort and a space as delimiter. However the computation time could be more than O(n2).

Comment: ```
a.join(',')
```
? :-D

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of real answers given and one of the best answers is also accepted.

Here I made a method which takes two lists {no matter what type(int,double,String) of list} and gives the bool return.

**Full Code with example**

```
void main() {
  List x = [1, 2, 3];
  List y = [2, 3, 1];
  bool success = isTwoListAreSame(x, y);
  print('=> $success'); // true

  List x2 = ["A", "B", "C"];
  List y2 = ["P", "Q", "R"];

  bool success2 = isTwoListAreSame(x2, y2);
  print('=> $success2'); // false

  List x3 = ["A", "B", "C"];
  List y3 = ["A", "B"];

  bool success3 = isTwoListAreSame(x3, y3);
  print('=> $success3'); // false
}
```

**Method**

```
/// this method made for only same length of list
/// no matter elements of list are in order or not.
bool isTwoListAreSame(List list1, List list2) {
  // if both list are empty
  // then no need no compare
  // return true directly
  if (list1.isEmpty && list2.isEmpty) {
    return true;
  } else if (list1.length == list2.length) {
    // if both list have equal length
    // take first list every element and compare with second list every element
    // if all element are same it will return true
    final bool isSame = list1.every(
      (e1) {
        return list2.any(
          (e2) {
            return e1 == e2;
          },
        );
      },
    );

    return isSame;
  } else {
    // when both list are not equal length
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the following code in the Dart utils that I maintain for one of my projects. It doesn't only work for lists, but for any `Iterable` things: two iterables are equal if they yield elements that are `==` in the same order, and both yield the same amount of elements. Moreover, if the yielded elements are not `==`, but are both `Iterable`, they are also tested using the `equals` method. (Therefore it behaves in the way analogous to the `equal?` predicate from Scheme and `equalp` from Common Lisp.)

If the sequences produced by both iterables are infinite and perpetually identical, the function can never terminate, but if you're only using it on lists, there is no such concern.

```
extension Relatable<T> on Iterable<T> {
    bool equals(Iterable<T> other) {

    if (this == other) {
      return true;
    }

    var it = iterator;
    var that = other.iterator;
 
    while(true) {
      if (it.moveNext()) {
        if (that.moveNext()) {
          if (it.current != that.current) {
            if (it.current is Iterable && that.current is Iterable) {
              // elements aren't `==`, but they both are
              // Iterable - test recursively using the
              // `equals` method
              Iterable its = it.current as Iterable;
              Iterable thats = that.current as Iterable;
              if (!its.equals(thats)) {
                return false;
              }
            }
            else {
              // elements aren't `==` and aren't Iterable
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          // `other` is shorter than `this`
          return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (that.moveNext()) {
          // `other` is longer than `this`
          return false;
        }
        else {
          // both iterables have the same number of elements
          // and we haven't found any non-equal elements
          // so we conclude that they are equal
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```