# How do I compare two lists as being equal and containing the same objects, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have two lists:

```dart
List fruits = ['apples', 'bananas'];
List foods = ['apples', 'bananas'];
```

How can I compare fruits and foods and ensure that both lists have the same objects in the same order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to compare lists for equality (rather than identity) is by using the Equality classes from the following package

```dart
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';
```

E.g.,

```dart
Function eq = const ListEquality().equals;
print(eq(fruits, foods)); // => true
```

This works for your case because the `fruits` and `foods` contain corresponding arguments that are `identical()`. If you want to (deeply) compare lists that might contain other collections then instead use:

```dart
Function deepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
List list1 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
List list2 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
print(    eq(list1, list2)); // => false
print(deepEq(list1, list2)); // => true
```

There are other Equality classes that can be combined in many ways, including equality for `Map`s. You can even perform an **unordered** (deep) comparison of collections:

```dart
Function deepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals;
```

For details see the [package API documentation](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection). As usual, to use such a package you must list it in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  collection: any
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this and this won't be a complete list for sure. But anyways:

Every solution I present, would require a length check beforehand `fruits.length == foods.length`, so I am leaving that out to keep it short.

The obvious solution would be to iterate over the length, but I guess, that's not what you want otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question:

```dart
var equals = true;
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  if (fruits[i] != foods[i]) {
    equals = false;
    break;
  }
}
print(equals);
```

Another solution could be to use `fold`:

```dart
var index = 0;
equals = fruits.fold(true, (result, item) => result && item == foods[index++]);
print(equals);
```

The downside of this approach is, that it would keep iterating even if there was a mismatch.

Another possibility would be using `firstWhere`

```dart
var index = 0;
equals = fruits.firstWhere((item) => item != foods[index++], orElse: () => null) == null;
print(equals);
```

The downside of this approach is the null check, because it may not be obvious that this is a check for equality, but it would stop iterating once the first mismatch is found.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter has `foundation.dart` class `listEquals` method which compare the list

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  List fruits = ['apples', 'bananas'];
  List foods = ['apples', 'bananas'];
  print(listEquals(fruits, foods)); // true

}
```

Also, `setEquals` and `mapEquals` are there to compare `map` and `set`.