# Why does Dart sometimes consider Objects as not equal if one is const?

Tags: dart

I've got `ClassA` which holds a a `List<ClassB>`. `ClassB` has an string attribute.

If I now have one const Object of `ClassA` with a list of an object of `ClassB` completly identical to another **non const** Object of `ClassA` with the exact same object of `ClassB` then these two are not treated as equal.

Why? I could not find any documentation referencing this occurance when looking any documentation regarding equality.

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('equal', () {
    const ClassA a1 = ClassA(list: [ClassB(text: "Mo")]);
    ClassA a2 = ClassA(list: [ClassB(text: "Mo"),]);

    expect(const [ClassB(text: "Mo")], [ClassB(text: "Mo")]);//true
    expect(a1, equals(a2)); //false. Is only true when a2 is const.
  });
}

class ClassB {
  final String text;

  const ClassB({this.text});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ClassB &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          text == other.text;

  @override
  int get hashCode => text.hashCode;
}

class ClassA {
  final List<ClassB> list;
  const ClassA({this.list});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ClassA &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          list == other.list;

  @override
  int get hashCode => list.hashCode;
}
```

I expected a1 and a2 as being equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `list` and `other.list` are only equal if they are both const (and with the same, const values, of course), as they are then the same object.

`package:collections` has some useful comparison tools.

Your equals operator can be rewritten as:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
...  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ClassA && ListEquality<ClassB>().equals(list, other.list);
```

You will also need to change your implementation of `hashCode` as, with the change above, the classes are now `equal` but have differing `hashCode`s. See edit below...

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713572/how-do-i-compare-two-lists-as-being-equal-and-containing-the-same-objects-in-da).

*Edit*

```
class ClassA {
  final List<ClassB> list;
  final ListEquality<ClassB> equality = const ListEquality<ClassB>();

  const ClassA({this.list});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
      other is ClassA && equality.equals(list, other.list);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => equality.hash(list);
}
```

Comment: Thats what I guessed, but why is `expect(const [ClassB(text: "Mo")], [ClassB(text: "Mo")]);` `true` then? One is const, the other is not.

Comment: Good question, because `print(const [ClassB(text: "Mo")] == [ClassB(text: "Mo")]);` prints `false`!

Comment: Yeah, I now know why it works with equals(), but not with ==.   
Documentation of equals() Matcher:  
*For [Iterable]s and [Map]s, this will recursively match the elements. To handle cyclic structures a recursion depth [limit] can be provided. The default limit is 100. [Set]s will be compared order-independently.*

This is also the reason why ClassA would not work with equals(), as it isn't a List/Map. That clarified it, thank you!

Comment: How would I need to rewrite the `hashCode` with your implementation?

Comment: The reason it works with `expect` is that `expect` recognizes lists specially. The Dart `List` implementations don't override `operator==`, so two list objects are only equal if they are the same object. The `expect` function considers two lists equal if they have equal elements, not just if they are equal as lists.