# 2 same content arrays are not equal in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a question.
When working with Dart, I can't check to see if 2 arrays are equal.
(in other languages, I can do with ==)
In fact, I just can do that == with String or number.

```dart
List arr1 = [1,2,3];
List arr2 = [1,2,3];

if (arr1 == arr2) {
  print("equal");
} else {
  print("not equal");
}
```

// Output: not equal.

So I wonder how does that make sense. I mean, How we can do if the == is just work for the cases of String or number (if the values compared are the same).
How do I have to do if I want to check that kind of comparison (equal) for List, Map, ..
It just work for String & number.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr1` and `arr2` are different instances of an object of type `List`. By default different instances are always different.
When a class implements a custom `==` operator it can override this behavior. Some classes have a custom implementation by default like `int` and `String`.
This can easily be done for immutable objects but not for mutable. One reason is that usually the `hashCode` is calculated from the values stroed in a class and the `hashCode` must not change for an instance because this can for example cause that an instance stored in a map can't be retrieved anymore when the hashcode of the key changed.

As a workaround there is a library that provides helper functions to compare lists/iterables.

```dart
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  if (const IterableEquality().equals([1,2,3],[1,2,3])) {
  // if (const SetEquality().equals([1,2,3].toSet(),[1,2,3].toSet())) {
      print("Equal");
  } else {
      print("Not equal");
  }
}
```