Why does Dart Stream Controller return different streams from its "stream" getter?
I'm working with dart as part of a hobby project and I found something kind of strange, namely the StreamController class as part of the Dart:async library returns different streams each time you call the stream getter.
This doesn't seem to be well documented, per dart:async docs:
StreamController
A controller with the stream it controls.

This controller allows sending data, error and done events on its stream.

This class can be used to create a simple stream that others can listen on, and to push events to that stream.

It's possible to check whether the stream is paused or not, and whether it has subscribers or not, as well as getting a callback when either of these change.

StreamController.stream
The stream that this controller is controlling.

Which all seems to imply that the StreamController has some ownership over the Stream object.
Essentially I have the following codeblock (Feel free to try this in dartpad.dev):
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final streamController = StreamController<int>();
  print('streams identical: ${
        identical(streamController.stream,                   
                  streamController.stream)}');
}

I would expect to see in the output:
streams identical: true

I actually get
streams identical: false

This seems to imply to me that "ownership" is transferred to the caller of the stream getter.  In my personal opinion this seems like odd behavior for a pass-by-reference language.
I'm partial to just implementing an observer but I'm limited by the API of FirebaseAuth which in this case I'm mocking for a test which implements AuthChange observers with streams.
I can work around this, but I'm just looking for some insight into why this would be implemented this way and why the developers would choose to exclude this nuance from documentation.

Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800510/2-same-content-arrays-are-not-equal-in-dart

Note the comment in stream_controller.dart - The controller returns a new stream each time it's queried, but doesn't have to cache the result. To allow for this _ControllerStream overrides hashCode and equals. So, while the two streams are not identical they are equal. I.E. streamController.stream == streamController.stream
