# What is the Correct way of listening ObservableList adding and removing?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, observablelist

I have next code:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created();

  @published ObservableList persons = toObservable([]);

  handleAdd() {
    persons.add({'name': 'jhon', 'lastName': 'Doe'});
  }

  handleRemove() {
    persons.remove({'name': 'jhon', 'lastName': 'Doe'});
  }
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```dart
<polymer name="my-element">
  <template>
    <template repeate="{{p in persons}}">
      {{p['name']}} {{p['lastName']}}
    </template>
    <button on-click="{{handleAdd}}">add person</button>
    <button on-click="{{handleRemove}}">remove person</button>
  <template>
</polymer>
```

when debugging, it is added and removed from the internal list of objects. However, it never shows the elements as added in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This code line has no effect

```dart
persons.remove({'name': 'jhon', 'lastName': 'Doe'});
```

because

```dart
print({'name': 'jhon', 'lastName': 'Doe'} == {'name': 'jhon', 'lastName': 'Doe'});
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/daafd4d98f58f63ea8a0)

prints `false` because for collections Dart compares identity not content.
There are helpers available. See [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516)

What you can do instead is

```dart
persons.removeWhere((p) => p['name'] == 'jhon' && p['lastName'] == 'Doe');
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3d6cb61b9383e006f73f)

This doesn't work because in Dart you can't access elements of a Map using dot-notation

```dart
<template repeate="{{p in persons}}">
  {{p.name}} {{p.lastName}}
</template>
```

If you change this to

```dart
<template repeate="{{p in persons}}">
  {{p['name']}} {{p['lastName']}}
</template>
```

it should work as intened.