# comparing two string lists and check if they have at least one same string

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to compare two String list with each other and check if at least the have one exact same string or not ..

For example:

```
List<String> list1 = ['1','2','3','4'];

List<String> list2 = ['1','5','6','7'];
```

In this case I will do action cause both have same string which is `1`, and it could be more than one exact same string and the action will be the same.

But if they don't have any similar strings then I will do another action.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: @MatthewPage of course i know! but this doesn't work with looping :)

Answer (score 20):

You can do it with `any()` and `contains()` method:

```
if (list1.any((item) => list2.contains(item))) {
    // Lists have at least one common element
} else {
    // Lists DON'T have any common element
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @lamatat if you found an answer helpful and it resolves your issue, please accept the answer :)

Comment: both answers are helpful and working and answered the same time .. i don't know to accept which so i uovoted both lol

Answer (score 9):

`Set` has an `intersection` that does that:

```
list1.toSet().intersection(list2.toSet()).length > 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart mentions some other handy features to compare lists or iterables (not directly related to the question though)

Comment: Instead of converting both to sets, you can als just do `list1.any(list2.toSet().contains)`.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```dart
bool hasCommonElement = list1.any(list2.contains);
```