# How to compare arrays in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dart

I'm trying to compare two array values existence, but inside iterator the comparison `every` doesn't seem to work.

```
void main() {
  var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var array2 = [2, 3, 4, 1];
  print("Arrays are equal: ${compareArrays(array1, array2)}");
}

bool compareArrays(array1, array2) {

  if (array1.length == array2.length) {
    return array1.every( (value) => array2.contains(value) );
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

and so I'm getting below said error:

> Uncaught exception: TypeError: Closure 'compareArrays_closure': type
>   '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(int) => bool'

How could I iterate array through each values and whats wrong I'm doing above?

Comment: If what you need is only checking for the list equality you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333042/8745788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Dart can't infer exactly what types `array1` and `array2` are, so it doesn't know what the function `contains` should be. If you specify types for the function arguments, it will work as expected fine:

```
void main() {
  var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var array2 = [2, 3, 4, 1];
  print("Arrays are equal: ${compareArrays(array1, array2)}");
}

bool compareArrays(List array1, List array2) {

  if (array1.length == array2.length) {
    return array1.every( (value) => array2.contains(value) );
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh! what a minor mistake I have done, LOL, forget to mention function parameter type, this happens when you came from `JS`, thanks