# How to check is a List container all the elements in another List

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a nice way to determine if all items in one list exist in another list.

I have tried various methods, but they get uglier and uglier as I go and I'm hoping there is an elegant solution out there somewhere.

**Attempt 1:**

```
if (listOne.contains(ListTwo))
```

This doesn't error, but also doesn't work. I assume it is looking to find not the items but the actual list which it wont.

**Attempt 2:**

```
if (listOne.toString().substring(1,listOne.toString().length - 1).contains(listTwo.toString().substring(1,listTwo.toString().length - 1)))
```

This actually works, but it just seems fragile to me

> **Question: What is an elegant solution to determine if all the items in one list are in another list?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart)

Comment: `var one = [1,3,4,6,8,9];
  var two = [6];
  
  print(one.toSet().containsAll(two));`

Comment: @pskink Perfect, thank again. Did you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one-liner (i assume that lists dont care about the duplicated items):

```
print(listOne.toSet().containsAll(listTwo));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
main() {
 List<String> list1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
  List<String> list2 = ["item2", "item1"];

  if (containsAll(list1, list2)) {
    print("it contains all");
  } else {
    print("it doesn't contain all");
  }
}

bool containsAll(List<dynamic> checkWhere, List<dynamic> checkWhich) {
  checkWhere.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  checkWhich.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

  for (int i = 0; i < checkWhich.length; i++) {
    print(checkWhich.length);
    if (checkWhich[i] != checkWhere[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```