# How to check if a List contains a List, and remove the List from the List

Tags: dart

I am trying to search a List to see if it contains another list, using `.contains`

However, it doesn't work.

```
void main() {
  List cake = [[true, 8728], [true, 3231], [true, 9981], [true, 4323], [true, 6456], [true, 3244], [true, 4355]];
  print(cake.contains([true, 9981])); // Prints false, although cake contains [true, 9981]
  List piece = [true, 9981];
  cake.remove(piece); // Does not remove [true, 9981] from the List cake
  print(cake); // List remains unaltered
}
```

I assume `.contains` and `.remove` can't search for or remove a List from a List? Am I doing something wrong? Otherwise, what's the best way to do what I'm trying to do, other than looping through the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `List<E>.contains` and `List<E>.remove` (among other `List` methods) use `E.operator ==` to match the item, but your element type is `List`, and [`List.operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/operator_equals.html) checks only for object identity instead of performing a deep equality check. (That is, `[1] == [1]` is `false` because each instance of `[1]` is a separate `List` object.)

One way to do what you want is instead to use [`List.removeWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) with [a deep `List` equality check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404516).