# find index in multilist in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

Please help me out,

i have a multilist with a type of string:

```html
List<List<String>> mergedList = [["39", "Green"], ["40", "Blue"], ["39", "Blue"], ["40", "Green"]]
```

i want to find the index of ["39", "Green"] by using indexOf like this:

```
mergedList.indexOf(["39","Green"])
```

but instead it always return -1.

please help where did i do wrong

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788633/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use `indexWhere` and compare with `element.toString()` 
full code

```
void main() {
  List<List<String>> mergedList = [["39", "Green"], ["40", "Blue"], ["39", "Blue"], ["40", "Green"]];
    
  var pos = mergedList.indexWhere((element) => element.toString() == ["39","Green"].toString()); 
  print(pos);
  
   var pos1 = mergedList.indexWhere((element) => element.toString() == ["39","Blue"].toString()); 
  print(pos1);
}
```

output

```
0
2
```

working demo

[image]