# Using List<int> as the key for a Map always returns null

Tags: dart

To solve a problem, I'm pre-populating a Map and then trying to pull the answer out of the map later when needed.

The map is populated like this:

```
var cycles = {
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] : [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] : [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
  ...
};
```

Later, a function is called like this:

```
print(pullAnswerFromMap([1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0], 1000000000));
```

Where the `pullAnswerFromMap` function is defined as:

```
return cycles[cells][N % 14 == 0 ? 14 : N % 14];
```

The `cycles` map will have every possible key - all 256 lists of 8 bits.

But when running the code with an example to test, I get the following:

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

So, before the return statement, I added `print(cycles);` - The map prints just fine. All data is there.
Then I added `print(cycles[[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]]);` which prints `null`, even though I can see that it exists in the map in the output from the previous print statement.

So it seems as though the key isn't based on the equality of the lists, but somehow on the specific instance (memory address?) of the list. A new list with the same elements in the same order will return null when trying to retrieve the value from the map.

My question is: How can I fix this so that `cycles[[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]]` doesn't return `null` and instead returns the `List<List<int>>` that it is associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it seems as though the key isn't based on the equality of the lists, but somehow on the specific instance (memory address?) of the list.

`Map` (which by default is a `LinkedHashMap`) uses the key type's `operator ==` and `hashCode` to determine if two keys are the same.  `List` does not override those; two separate `List` instances will never compare equal, and therefore your attempts to look up `Map` values from a `List` key will always fail.

A few ways to fix that would be:

- Explicitly use [the `LinkedHashMap` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashMap.html) so that you can provide your own callbacks for computing hash codes and for determining if two keys are equal.
- Create a custom class for the `Map` key, where your class has a `List<int>` member and overrides `operator ==` and `hashCode` appropriately.
- If all of your keys have the same number of elements, consider using a [`Tuple`](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple) instead of a `List`.

See [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart) for how to do a deep equality check on `List`s.

Also note that if you use `List`s as a `Map` key, you must ensure that you do not mutate those `List` instances afterward.  The `Map` will not know when any of its keys has been mutated from under it, breaking future lookups.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see being able to do this is to reference the keys through `cycles.keys`. So `cycles[cycles.keys.first]` works perfectly and returns what's necessary. So to achieve what you want, you could do a search function that finds the key that you need.

Example:

```
void main() {
  bool compareList(List<int> list1, List<int> list2) {
    for(int x = 0; x < list1.length; x++) {
      if(list1[x] != list2[x]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  List<int> key;
  List<int> input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
  for(int x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
    if(compareList(cycles.keys.elementAt(x), input)) {
      key = cycles.keys.elementAt(x);
      break;
    }
  }
  
  print(cycles[key]);
}

Map<List<int>, List<List<int>>> cycles = {
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] : [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] : [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
};
```

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I don't see an example

Comment: @loganrussell48 I added the example

Answer (score 1):

For an easy solution without writing too much code (and encouraging good data behavior), consider the [package:fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections), which has truly immutable lists as `IList`, which can be used directly as Map keys because they have a good == comparison.