# remove item from map<datetime, List> in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have an object _events with datatype Map<DateTime, List>.
it stores list of events of a particular date. for now i am not aware how to remove a particular event from _events

```
 Map<DateTime, List> _events;
```

Comment: `_events[someDate].removeMethod(...)` - where `removeMetod` is one of: `remove,
removeAt,
removeLast,
removeRange,
removeWhere`

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeWhere()`

Remove based on **Date**

```
_events.removeWhere((key, value) => key == myDateObject);
```

Remove based on **Event List**

```
_events.removeWhere((key, value) => value == eventList);
```

In the second case, do remeber it will apply default list comparision which means both lists should have same objects in the same order. If you want you can provide your custom list comparisions. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart)