# How to Compare List of Class Object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to compare one `List<MediaItem>` with another `List<MediaItem>`.
My MediaItem Class looks like:

```
class MediaItem
{
String id;
String title;
String description;
Duration duration;
}
```

Now, How to compare two `List<MediaItem>` ignoring `duration` parameter of `MediaItem` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333042/10285344 See this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `listEquals` from `flutter/foundation.dart` package:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

final isListAreEquals = listEquals(firstList, secondList);
```

Also you should implement method `equals` for your object. See [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) page for more information about `equals` method. Variables that are using in `equals` method are object identity parameters, you need to be careful with it (otherwise you may cause a situation, where some parameter is needed for comparison but it not listed in `equals`).