# Delete repeated data with Set in a nested list (Dart)

Tags: list, flutter, dart, set

I have problems removing repeated data from a nested list, I need to remove the records that are not repeated in the index 0 of the list, but the Set method is not doing anything when the list is nested.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      sections.add([items[i].sectionG, items[i].logo]);
    }

    sections = sections.toSet().toList();
```

[Imagen de la estructura de la lista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxUt1.png)

When I go through Set I get back the same structure as before.

Answer (score 1):

`operator ==` for most Dart objects, including `List`s, `Set`s, and `Map`s, checks only for object *identity* and [does not perform deep equality checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404516/).  That is, two separate `List` objects do not compare equal even if they contain the same elements.

You will need to create a `Set` that performs deep equality checks. [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides an `EqualitySet` class that can use a `ListEquality` object to compare `List` elements:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var listOfLists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],
  ];
  var set = EqualitySet.from(ListEquality<int>(), listOfLists);
  print(set); // Prints: {[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]}
}
```