# valuenotifier not updating the widget on udating the list

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../Data/Globalvariable.dart' as global;

class MenuBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final key = UniqueKey();
  // final pin;
  // MenuBar({this.pin='112'});
  @override
  _MenuBarState createState() {
    return _MenuBarState();
  }
}

class _MenuBarState extends State<MenuBar> {
  ValueNotifier<List<String>> st = ValueNotifier(global.pincode);
  Widget total() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: global.pincode.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = global.pincode[index];
        return Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {
              global.pincode.removeAt(index);
            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$item Removed')));
          },
          background: Container(color: Colors.red),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(item),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      builder: (context, n, menu) {
        print(global.pincode);
        return total();
      },
      child: total(),
      valueListenable: st,
    );
  }
}
```

this is my main file  i have a global file
and all of my working variables are there

```
Globalvariable.dart

library project.globals;
List<String> pincode = ['Select Pin','110084','110088'];
```

now as i am adding data into pincode valuenotifier should listen to it and update the widget automatically but it is not doing so i verified that using debug console it gets updated when i call setstate which is ok but i want to update widget as i add data to my list

[image]

this is to demonstrate what i said above that wigdet is updating on removal but not for addition

Comment: use st.notifyListeneres() instead of setState !

Comment: I think you have to use `st` somehow in `ValueListenableBuilder` `builder`, like `return total(st)`, otherwise it will return the same regardless of `st` value.

Comment: This is the third time I see this misconception, your `ValueNotifier<List<SomeType>>` will not know when the value is changed or not. See the source of `ValueNotifier`, it uses equality operator `==`. This won't work for lists, you are comparing the same List pointer with itself (even though List's  content changed). See this answer on list comparison in Dart https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333042/10830091

Comment: First of all let's get this out of the way. You cannot update your list like that `global.pincode.removeAt(index);`. You have to `st` instead `st.value.removeAt(index);`

Comment: After you have solved that issue. You have 2 solutions. A. forcefully tell ValueNotifier its value has changed `st.value = List.from(st.value)..removeAt(index);`  B. subclass ValueNotifier and define methods for adding/deleting elements within the list, calling notifyListeners manually within said methods.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use SetState if you already use ValueNotifier.

To update state, use: **st.value = *new value***.

Because you already wrap your child widget with ValueListenableBuilder, the state will automatically change **if value of st changes.**

---

ValueNotifier uses equality to detect change. For List, the dart compiler won't notice any change if you only add/remove value of the list.

To overcome the problem, you need to create a new list so that the dart compiler detects the change.

You can update your code like this:

```
return Dismissible(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    st.value = List.from(st.value)..removeAt(index);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$item Removed')));
  },
  background: Container(color: Colors.red),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(item),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Understanding the identify function (i.e. hashcode/equals) of your objects is helpful here so the ValueNotifier can detect the change

Comment: Or you can create a `ValueNotifier` subclass and call `notifyListeners` yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378538

Answer (score 5):

To make life easier, you can write a class that extends ValueNotifier<List> and define methods add and remove, as in the example below. and then just use `_yourNotifier.add(newValue);` So u don't need to repeat List.from(st.value)..removeAt(index) and so on.

```
class ValueNotifierList<T> extends ValueNotifier<List<T>> {
  ValueNotifierList(List<T> value) : super(value);

  void add(T valueToAdd) {
    value = [...value, valueToAdd];
  }

  void remove(T valueToRemove) {
    value = value.where((value) => value != valueToRemove).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ValueNotifier` with a list you should append to that list `st` using `st.value.add()`, modifying the `global.pincode` list won't reflect unless you make that global list a `ValueNotifier`.

So you'll either have `st.value.add()` or in your global file `ValueNotifier<List<String>> pincode = ValueNotifier(<String>[...]);` with a `valueListenable: global.pincode` and modifications using `global.pincode.value.xyz`

Comment: This is a part of the solution yes, updates should be made via ValueNotifier object `st` and not the global list `global.pincode`. The second part of the solution concerns list equality and how `ValueNotifier` knows when it should notify its listeners. ValueNotifier sees the new value as different from the old value via equality i.e. `==` operator, then if there's a difference a notification occurs. With lists, that won't work because of how list equality works. Please see my comments above.