# Flutter: How to update ValueNotifier for individual List item

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List builder with is creates cards with content. In this card i have a button and Text widget. Basically, i want to update Text widget when i press the button. I tried to use ValueNotifier and it worked. But it updating values of every List item.

**Here is main functionality:**

I created ValueNotifier variable

```
class SelectedOrganizationStructure extends StatefulWidget {
  static ValueNotifier<String> lastLoginDate = ValueNotifier('Last login');
  final List<OrganizationUnitEntity> organizationStructure;
  const SelectedOrganizationStructure(this.organizationStructure, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectedOrganizationStructure> createState() =>
      _SelectedOrganizationStructureState();
}
```

And i set it to Text widget `Text(SelectedOrganizationStructure.lastLoginDate.value),` and when i press the button i set it's value to current date like this:

```
final _dateTime = DateTime.now();
final _loginDate = DateFormat('dd.MM HH:mm').format(_dateTime).toString();

onTap: () {
  SelectedOrganizationStructure.lastLoginDate.value = _loginDate
},
```

How i said before, this sets current date for all the card item in list builder. How can i make it update only card in witch button was pressed?

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

`ValueNotifier` only notifies its listeners when the value changes. However, if the value is a `List` like so:

```dart
final myListNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<String>>([]);
```

changing a single item like this:

```dart
myListNotifier.value.add('Hello');
```

does not notify the listeners because the list itself didn't change. Only an item within the list changed. To Dart, the list is the reference to the list object. That reference doesn't change every time you change the contents of the list.

There are a couple of solutions.

### Create a new list

If you create a new list with the updated content, then changing the `value` in the notifier will cause it to notify its listeners. This is demonstrated below:

```dart
final newList = myListNotifier.value.toList();
newList.add('Hello');
myListNotifier.value = newList;
```

That works and for most situations it is probably fine. After all, in most applications you aren't dealing with extremely long lists, so making a copy isn't a big deal.

However, there is another option.

### Notify the listeners yourself

Since `ValueNotifier` extends `ChangeNotifier` you can call `notifyListeners` yourself. However, this method has a `protected` annotation, which means you should only call it from a subclass.

Here is an example of creating a custom subclass:

```dart
class MyStateManager {
  final myListNotifier = ListNotifier();

  void send(String text) {
    myListNotifier.add(text);
  }
}

class ListNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<String>> {
  ListNotifier() : super([]);

  void add(String listItem) {
    value.add(listItem);
    notifyListeners();            // here
  }
}
```

In your `add` method, you update the contents of the list (without creating a new one), and then you manually notify the listeners as you would in a `ChangeNotifier`.