# How to compare List of Map(i.e List<Map>) in dart using equatable package?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, equatable

I need to compare a list of map (i.e List < Map >) in dart using equatable for to be used inside a bloc state class. But the problem is that equatable seems to not compare that list of map properties.

```
class WaterCartDetailState extends Equatable {
  final String? status;
  final WateCartDetailModel? result;
  final List<Map>? mapData;
  const WaterCartDetailState({this.status, this.result, this.mapData});

  WaterCartDetailState copyWith(
      {String? status, WateCartDetailModel? result, List<Map>? mapData}) {
    return WaterCartDetailState(
        status: status ?? this.status,
        result: result ?? this.result,
        mapData: mapData ?? this.mapData);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status, result, mapData];
}
```

Since equatable is not comparing the List of Map. I cannot emit new state changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart)

Comment: Partly.. but I want equatable to do the comparision.

Comment: What is the Map model? It is the Map<E, T> collection or a custom type which is defined by you?

Comment: It is just primitive map offered by dart not any custom type

Answer (score 3):

From [Docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating)

> **Equatable** properties should always be copied rather than modified. If
> an **Equatable** class contains a **List** or **Map** as properties, be sure to
> use **List.from** or **Map.from** respectively to ensure that equality is
> evaluated based on the values of the properties rather than the
> reference.

```
yield WaterCartDetailState(status, result, List<Map>.from(mapData));
```