# compare 2 List and return index value to true or false

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 lists of which items are coming from firebase.

```
final List listOfAnswers = ['Apple','Grape','Watermelon','Strawberry'];

final List selectedAnswers = ['Apple','Watermelon','Strawberry'];
```

I have used `Checkbox` of `flutter_multi_select_items` package widget in the UI in which I have to display `selectedAnswers` as already selected. To do that I tried creating so many functions but none of them are working.

```
       bool getSelectedOptions(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

            bool x = false;
             final List listOfAnswers = snapshot.docs[_counter.value]['options'];
             final List selectedAnswers =
                   snapshot.docs[_counter.value]['listOfSelectedOptions'];
             final indexes =
                   listOfAnswers .mapIndexed((index, element) => index).toList();

                   listOfAnswers .forEachIndexed((index, element) {

              for (int i = 0; i < selectedAnswers .length; i++) {

                 if (element == selectedAnswers [i]) {
                    print('index: $index, element: $element');
                     x = true;
               } else {
                   x = false;
               }
              }
      }
    });
    print(indexes);
    return x;
  }
```

above was one of many trials. Please suggest a better way to get a true or false bool value every time if the items in 2 lists match.
Thanks in advance

Edited : code for checkbox widget

```
MultiSelectCheckList(

  textStyles: const MultiSelectTextStyles(
      selectedTextStyle:
          TextStyle(
              color: Colors
                  .white,
              fontWeight:
                  FontWeight
                      .bold)),
  itemsDecoration: MultiSelectDecorations(
      selectedDecoration:
          BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors
                  .indigo
                  .withOpacity(
                      0.8))),
  listViewSettings:
      ListViewSettings(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    separatorBuilder:
        (context, index) =>
            const Divider(
      height: 0,
    ),
  ),
  controller: _controller,
  singleSelectedItem:
      false, // if true it will work like radio button
  items: List.generate(
    optionLength.length,
    (index) =>
        CheckListCard(
      value: mySnapshot
          .docs[_counter
                  .value]
              ['options']
              [index]
          .toString(),
      title: Text(mySnapshot
          .docs[_counter
                  .value]
              ['options']
              [index]
          .toString()),
      selectedColor:
          Colors.white,
      checkColor:
          Colors.indigo,
      selected:
          getSelectedOptions(
              mySnapshot),

     
      checkBoxBorderSide:
          const BorderSide(
              color: Colors
                  .blue),
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius
                .circular(
                    5),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onChange:
      (allSelectedItems,
          selectedItem) {},


),
```

Comment: Does [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404516/10157127) answer your question

Comment: Can you share code of how you create the checkboxes?

Comment: I don't quite understand you want to achieve you want to compare the checkbox which selected then compare the listOfanswer if the selected checkbox is exists on the list?

Comment: @Ivo please check code of checkboxes

Comment: @ArbiterChil  what i want is to get a selected value to true if a user have already selected any options . please look for `selected:  getSelectedOptions( mySnapshot)`, may be i am doing wrong. but you will understand what i really want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

judging from your code I think you want something like this:

```
bool getSelectedOptions(int index, QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  String answer = snapshot.docs[_counter.value]['options'][index];
  List selectedAnswers = snapshot.docs[_counter.value]['listOfSelectedOptions'];
  return selectedAnswers.contains(answer);
}
```

and change the

```
selected:
getSelectedOptions(
    mySnapshot),
```

to

```
selected:
getSelectedOptions(index, 
    mySnapshot),
```

Comment: It worked !!.. thank you so much. what was my mistake? please tell me if there are less because its been 3-4 months i am learning flutter . So many things to learn.

Comment: @VIP-Dev-Invisible your code didn't really check for which position you are checking it. It basically went for each of the 4 positions "does any of selected options exist in the list of all answers", and then of course says true for every position

Comment: @VIP-Dev-Invisible also if this answer helped you please upvote it and accept this answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: i would love to upvote  your answer but as i mentioned above .. i am new to programming and stack overflow . this is my second question and i  need to get 15 reputation to upvote an answer. thanks again.

Comment: @VIP-Dev-Invisible ah okay. Though accepting should always be possible, which also grants you 2 reputation