# check equality of two list how to check the elements of both them are equal not in index wise

Tags: flutter, list, dart, equality

```
list1=["hello World","hello India"]

list2=["hello India","hello world"]
```

how could I check equality of this two list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare Lists for equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404516/how-can-i-compare-lists-for-equality-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

You can try compare sorted copies of the lists, like

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var list1 = ["hello world","hello India"];
  var list2 = ["hello India", "hello world"];

  print(ListEquality().equals(list1.toList()..sort(), list2.toList()..sort()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code refer [**`collection`**](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

```
void main() {
  List list1 = ["hello World", "hello India"]; 
  List list2 = ["hello India", "hello world"];

  print(ListEquality().equals(list1, list2));
}
```

Result - false