# My flutter app isn't reaching the paint method

Tags: flutter

my app isn't working as intended, and as far as I can guess, I'm doing it correctly. I have print statements everywhere, and the points length returns 0 at first in the console and then doesnt print again. The "line drawn" statement isn't even being triggered, the pan print statements are working fine, I dont know what part of my code is off so that the for loop isnt being triggered.

```
void main() async {

  //ensure flutter widgets are binding
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

//firebase

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

// end firebase


  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Offset> points = [];

  void handlePanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    print("handled Pan Update");
    setState(() {
      points.add(details.localPosition);
    });
  }

  void handlePanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    print("handled Drag End");
    setState(() {
      points.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey[50], // set the background color of the container
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: handlePanUpdate,
          onPanEnd: handlePanEnd,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: PaintField(points),
            size: Size.infinite,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class PaintField extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;

  PaintField(this.points);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

    print("Points length: ${points.length}");

    for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(points[i - 1], points[i], paint);
      print("Line drawn!");
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PaintField oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.points != points;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CustomPaint` doesn't repaint because your `oldDelegate.points` equals `points` (in `shouldRepaint`; you can return `true` there as a test to see it working). You are comparing those lists by equality, which checks the references. And because you still pass the same list that you initialized in `_MyAppState`, the reference points to the same object.

Instead of doing just `.add()` in your `setState`s, you may assign a new, updated list to the field, so that the reference changes, like so:

```dart
    setState(() {
      points = [...points, details.localPosition];
      // or this way, whichever you like more:
      points = List.of(points)..add(details.localPosition);
    });
```

...and the same with clearing the list. This is why immutability is such an important topic in Flutter :)

Answer (score 1):

As Albert described, the is issue coming because of [list equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404516/10157127). Also I would suggest you can take advantage of `CustomPainter` super constructor with ValueNotifier, NO need to call setState.

```dart
 ValueNotifier<List<Offset>> points = ValueNotifier<List<Offset>>([]);

  void handlePanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    print("handled Pan Update");

    RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset _localPosition = object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    points.value = [...points.value, _localPosition];
  }

  void handlePanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    points.value = [];
  }
```

```dart
class PaintField extends CustomPainter {
  final ValueNotifier<List<Offset>> points;

  PaintField(this.points) : super(repaint: points);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 25.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < points.value.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(points.value[i - 1], points.value[i], paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PaintField oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.points != points;
  }
}
```

Comment: `repaint: ...` is a very good solution but `[...points.value, _localPoisition]` ca be a very costly operation

Comment: how can I deal with this. Tried overriding hash&equals for Offset class/creating new class, didnt work

Comment: for example: `class ListenableList<T> extends DelegatingList<T> with ChangeNotifier {
ListenableList() : super(<T>[]);

@override
void add(T value) {
super.add(value);
notifyListeners();
}
}` and now you can use it: `final points = ListenableList<Offset>();` instead of `ValueNotifier<List<Offset>> points = ValueNotifier<List<Offset>>([])`

Comment: and of course instead of `points.value = [...points.value, _localPosition];` just use `points.add(_localPosition);`

Comment: thanks & nice, I was just thinking to passing new key 

Comment: btw another, not obvious solution: `class FooPainter extends CustomPainter with ChangeNotifier {
Color _color = Colors.white;

set color(Color color) {
_color = color;
notifyListeners();
}
...` - so you dont need to pass any `Listenable` to `repaint: ...` and use directly `notifyListeners()` inside a `CustomPainter` setter or method

Comment: Cool. gonna experiment this.